# Paypal options for handling credit card processing

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to understand how to add in the ability to handle credit card transactions in an asp .net web app.  We want the ability to take the credit cards on the customer web site, send the transaction via a webservice call to paypal, and then return some information in the web service call.  the customer web site never wants to open another window to paypal or take the user away from the customer site.

The problem that I am running into is that there are many development options for paypal, and this is rather confusing to me.  I've read through developer docs.  I've created some sandbox accounts.  The problem is that I am unsure of the next steps.  Any suggestions are definitely appreciated.

TIA,

Wally

Comment: After a bunch of floundering, I think I have something working here.  Hooray.  It just took some more experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to find a few different options if you dig into this.

- Website Payments Pro 2.0 (DoDirectPayment)
- Payments Pro 2.0 (PayFlow)
- REST DCC (deprecated)
- Braintree Payments

I would recommend you go straight to Braintree.  The other stuff is old and isn't being supported as well as it used to.